# Yii2 formatter locale not working

Tags: yii2, date-formatting, yii2-basic-app, dateformatter

I'm having a problem with the yii2 date formatter, it doesn't use the locale that I have set. The global language is set to de-DE, it seems to take effect everywhere except for the date formatter. I've tryed to set the formatter locale in the config file like this:

```
 'formatter' => [
        'dateFormat' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',            
        'decimalSeparator' => ',',
        'thousandSeparator' => ' ',
        'currencyCode' => 'EUR',
        'locale'=>'de_DE'
   ],
```

and also directly before using the formatter in code:

```
Yii::$app->formatter->locale = 'de-DE';
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime('2014-01-01');
```

but it formats the date to Jan 1, 2014 10:04:36 AM.
Any ideas?

Comment: The question is somehow wrong. It is no locale issue occuring with the code, it is caused by a wrong property usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The param `dateFormat` only has effect for `asDate()`. For `asDatetime()` set `datetimeFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

possible reason:
check and make sure that php-intl extension is installed.

see: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-i18n#parameter-formatting

Comment: that's not enough for an answer

Comment: provide more details on you answer